# Vertical nav bar is overlapping main body when i resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fairly new to coding less than 6 months and am working on my first paid website and I've run into an issue i'm really not sure how to fix. thanks for the help. I've already tried setting margins but CSS is tricky so maybe i'm not doing enough i'm really not sure how to fix

[This is what the page looks like when down sized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CTTY.png)
[This is what the page looks like at regular size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoTvH.jpg)

```
.login-page{
  width: 360px;
  padding: 10% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.header-logo{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.header{
  text-align: right;
  float: right
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(160, 143, 70, 0.4);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img src="header-logo.png" class="header-logo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#news">Store</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <h1 class="register-header">Register</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Create</button>
      <p class="message">Already Registered? <a href="#">Log-in</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class=:login-form>
      <h1 class="login-header">Log-In</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Log-in</button>
      <p class="message">Not Registered? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Consider looking into a CSS framework like Bootstrap or similar. Any such framework will have solved these and thousands of other problems you'll run into.

Comment: Take a look at [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) in CSS to handle mobile view issues.

Comment: didn't even think about media query and honestly didn't know bootstrap was a thing thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it `clear:both` for login div in mobile mode. It is due to div `.login-page` where you gave `margin:auto` to make it centralized.

```css
.login-page{
  width: 360px;
  padding: 10% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.header-logo{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
.header{
  text-align: right;
  float: right
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(160, 143, 70, 0.4);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media(max-width:767px){
.login-page{
clear: both;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <img src="header-logo.png" class="header-logo">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#news">Store</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <br>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <h1 class="register-header">Register</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Create</button>
      <p class="message">Already Registered? <a href="#">Log-in</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class=:login-form>
      <h1 class="login-header">Log-In</h1>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password">
      <button>Log-in</button>
      <p class="message">Not Registered? <a href="#">Register</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```